# Horizontal Scroll at the click in React Native

Tags: react-native

I have a horizontal ScrollView which I want to scroll at the click.
Below is my code:

```
<TouchableOpacity>
  <Text>Left</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>;
<ScrollView
  horizontal={true}
  showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
  contentContainerStyle={styles.horizontalView}
>
  .....
</ScrollView>;
```

I want my ScrollView contents to scroll left when user clicks on `left`. I know there is ref, but I dont know how to use it. I am very new to react-native. I am not able to figure out a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

create reference for the scroll(make sure you imported useRef):

```
<ScrollView
  horizontal={true}
  showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
  contentContainerStyle={styles.horizontalView}
  ref={scrollRef}
>
```

Add:

```
  const scrollRef = useRef(null);
```

Add

```
scrollRef.current.scrollTo({ x: -50})
```

to your button Press handler

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#scrollto

**(In this example the scroll will jump 50 units to the left, play with it with positive/negative numbers)**